# Trigger a syslog message on ASR9k

Tags: cisco, cisco-asr, syslog

I want to send a syslog message from  ASR9k.
E.g i want to send the message(trigger) "hello world" from my ASR9k. Please suggest the command used for same.

In one of the other blogs, i read:
send log [Text Here]
e.g.

```
Cisco# send log Hello World
```

This will send a SEV 2 message to the logging buffer, and test your syslog settings and alert handling.

However, i could not apply the same on ASR9k.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above requirement worked for me using the below command on ASR9k

```
logmsg [your message]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `send` command is used to send messages between users logged into the same router.

> send
>   - To send messages to one or all terminal lines, use the **send** EXEC command.
>
> **send** {*line-number* | * | **aux** *number* | **console** *number* | **tty** *number* | **vty** *number*}
>
> **Syntax Description**
>
> [image]
>
> **Defaults**
>
> No messages are sent.
>
> **Command Modes**
>
> EXEC
>
> **Command History**
>
> [image]
>
> **Usage Guidelines**
>
> After entering this command, the system prompts for the message to be
>   sent, which can be up to 500 characters long. Enter **Ctrl-Z** to end
>   the message. Enter **Ctrl-C** to abort this command.
>
> ---
>
> **Caution:** Be aware that in some circumstances text sent using the **send** command may be interpreted as an executable command by the receiving device. For example, if the receiving device is Unix
>   workstation, and the receiving device is in a state (shell) where
>   commands can be executed, the incoming text (if a valid Unix command)
>   will be interpreted as a command. For this reason you should limit
>   your use of any unmonitored connection to a router that uses an
>   interactive shell.
>
> ---
>
> **Examples**
>
> The following example sends a message to all lines:
>
> ```
> 2509# send *
> Enter message, end with CTRL/Z; abort with CTRL/C:
> The system 2509 will be shut down in 10 minutes for repairs.^Z
> Send message? [confirm]
> 2509#
> ***
> ***
> *** Message from tty0 to all terminals:
> ***
> The system 2509 will be shut down in 10 minutes for repairs.
> 2509#
> ```

I don't know of any command to send an arbitrary message to the syslog server. Cisco has documents describing the logging facility, e.g. [*System Message Logging*](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/access/wireless/software/guide/SysMsgLogging.html).

Comment: It worked using the below:  logmsg [your message]

Comment: Then you should post an answer and accept it so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.